# Google Sheets Calendar Monday start of week

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I don't want my weekday to start on a Sunday, who does? I want it to start on a Monday like most normal people, but impossible to find a way to do this. It's Ok on Google Calendar, you go to 'settings' but for Google Sheets Calendar, no idea. Can someone help please?

Comment: Hello Liane, can you provide a sample ?

Comment: What is a Google Sheets calendar?  It isn't clear what the problem is. See [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

From
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949?hl=en

> `WEEKNUM(date, [type])`
>
> `type` - [ OPTIONAL - default is 1 ] - A number representing the day
>   that a week starts on as well as the system used for determining the
>   first week of the year (1=Sunday, 2=Monday).

So, `weeknum(date,2)` will give week starting with Monday.